# UseEffect to run a function and that function set hook from another file

Tags: react-native

So what I want to do is throw my APIs in one file. This way it makes my app way more reusable.

Problem is that I don't know how to do what I'm doing.

My parent file holds all the Hooks I need for data.

I am trying to get the Parent file to call the API, run the call to get the data, then that data then calls back and sets the hook in the parent.

Parent File

```
import { handleDepartments } from './API/API';

export default function App() {
  const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDepartments;
  }, []);
```

The API file..

```
export const handleDepartments = async () => {
  console.log('getting Departments');
  const data = await axios
    .get(`URI`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'API_KEY',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setDepartments(response.data.departments);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track but its not a great idea to pass down a setState function into the api to update the parent component. Instead, its better practice to make the api call only return data, then the parent can decide how to deal with it.

Api:

```
export const handleDepartmentsApi = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`URI`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'API_KEY',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };
```

Parent:

```
 export default function App() {
  const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);

  const getDepartments = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await handleDepartmentsApi();
        setDepartments(response.data.departments)
    } catch (err) {
        //handle error or do whatever
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getDepartments();
  }, []);

  return (<></>)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. this does seem like a better approach